What's the best way to select an enum variant according to a non uniform probability?
I have an enum and I want to create instances of its variants by performing a random non uniform extraction. A possible solution involves using Rng::gen_range() from rand by trying to match the desired probabilities to the subranges that are assigned to each variant.
While it may work really well for a uniform distribution where each variant is matched against a single number found within the chosen range, I find it increasingly flaky and error-prone the more variants I need to handle: it's not immediately clear which probability each variant has assigned, and at the very least they would need to be added as comments somewhere.
Also, if for some reason I add or remove a variant after already having set up the subranges, I'll be obviously forced to adapt the remaining probabilities accordingly and this comes with the price of having to change one or both endpoints of almost every subrange, which is already as bad as it sounds.
I've tried alternative approaches, for example by matching against multiple simultaneous calls of Rng::gen_ratio() which lets you pass a fraction representing a precise probability, but it falls short again and even if it worked it feels way too awkward.
First of all, given n variants it would require handling 2^n different cases in the match block, but even if it weren't the case there's always the issue of not having any guarantee of a successful extraction actually happening. In the (false, ..., false) case I need to decide if I'm happy with returning an arbitrary variant (which would slightly alter its actual probability), or maybe opt to repeat the entire ordeal from the beginning, which doesn't sound too enticing.
The same goes for those cases where I end up with more than one simultaneous successful extraction, so I have to decide again which of the variants takes priority over the others. If instead I care about only one outcome at a time by matching against wildcards, I end up with the leftmost outcomes shadowing those that are positioned after them. In practice it means that the probability of a certain variant is also inherently influenced by that of all its predecessors.
#[derive(Debug)]
enum MyEnum {
   A,
   B,
   C
}

fn main() {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();

    // example 1
    match rng.gen_range(0..10) {
        0..=4 => dbg!(MyEnum::A), // 5/10
        5..=7 => dbg!(MyEnum::B), // 3/10
        8..10 => dbg!(MyEnum::C), // 2/10
        _ => unreachable!()
    };

    // example 2
    match (
        rng.gen_ratio(5, 10),
        rng.gen_ratio(3, 10),
        rng.gen_ratio(2, 10)
    ){
        (true, _, _) => dbg!(MyEnum::A),
        (_, true, _) => dbg!(MyEnum::B),
        (_, _, true) => dbg!(MyEnum::C),
        . . .
        (false, false, false) => // now what?
    };
}


Luckily the rand crate already provides the correct abstraction and functionality for achieving the task at hand. This is known as a weighted distribution and it can be sampled by using the WeightedIndex type. Adapting the example in the docs, it can be used like this:
use rand::distributions::{Distribution, WeightedIndex};

#[derive(Debug)]
enum MyEnum {
    A,
    B,
    C,
}

fn main() {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();

    // the total number of events is the sum of the values passed to WeightedIndex::new()
    let items = [(MyEnum::A, 5), (MyEnum::B, 3), (MyEnum::C, 2)];
    let dist = WeightedIndex::new(items.iter().map(|item| item.1)).unwrap();

    dbg!(&items[dist.sample(&mut rng)].0);
}

Additionally, if the number of variants is pretty high and listing them all manually is inconvenient, the crate strum provides the EnumIter derive macro for enabling iteration over enum variants (it only works for enums that don't contain any lifetime bounds, as explained in the docs). Please check out this other question for further details.
